# JavaFX get specific pane size

Tags: java, javafx

How can I find out size of specific pane, I Have anchorPane in another panes. I want to track it size when window is resized something simular to scene on resize lissiner:

```
    scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
            old_width = newSceneWidth.intValue();
            System.out.println("Width: " + old_width);

        }
    });
    scene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {
            old_height = newSceneHeight.intValue();
            System.out.println("Height: " + old_height);
        }
    });
```

[image]

I want to track last panes size. P.S. fx:id=pane

Comment: `pane.widthProperty().addListener(...)`, etc?

Comment: @James_D this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   pane.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {

            System.out.println("Height2: " + newSceneHeight);
        }
    });
    pane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {

            System.out.println("Width2: " + newSceneWidth);

        }
    });
```